# How to keep a grid of cols without breaking on a new row?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I´m trying to set up a grid of images everything arranges fine until I set the last column instead of staying in the same row it breaks the line and goes down.

I tried using smaller columns instead of 2 col-6 in the same row one small and one bigger or even not matching the 12 maximum, col-4 col-4, col-5 col-6...
On all cases the grid breaks off on a new row.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6" style="width:100%;"><img src="image.png"  
    style="width: 100%" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="col-12" style="width: 100%"><img src="image.png" 
        style="width: 100%" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-6" style="width:100%;"><img src="image.png" 
        style="width: 100%" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-6" style="width:100%;"><img src="image.png" 
        style="width: 100%" alt=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the result i want is something like this;
[image]

but the result i get is something like this;
[image]

Comment: Your code above produces this https://www.bootply.com/pJtggljB6e (note the gutters) . Note you're missing a closing div too.

Comment: try `clear: both` after __green__ `div`

Answer (score 2):

Just need to tweak your DOM structure a little bit to get the result you're after. Oh, and in your example you're missing the closing tag for the parent row. Cheers;

```css
.row {
  min-height: 20rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6" style="background:blue">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12" style="background:green">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6" style="background:orange">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6" style="background:red">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that need to be addressed as part of the way you are organizing your code. 
- adding the 100% width inline will cause issues and supersedes the classes. 
- adding row will make it easier to read be more clear

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6"></div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-6"></div>
           <div class="col-6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```